# On key up event list show up in angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
 <body>
        <div ng-app="mvcapp" ng-controller="AngularController">
            <input type="text" class="myInput form-control" name="txtStorename" id="txtStorename" placeholder="Search for Store.." title="Type in a Store" data-error-message="Please enter StoreName" ng-model="sname"  >
            <ul id="myUL" ng-repeat="StoreList in Store| filter:{StoreName:sname}">
                <li ng-click="SelectedValue(StoreList.StoreName)">{{StoreList.StoreName}}</li>        
            </ul>
            <div ng-show="(Store|filter:sname).length==0" style="color:red;font-weight:bold">No Result Found</div>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
                var angular = angular.module('mvcapp', []);
                angular.controller('AngularController', function ($scope, $http) {

                        Getallitem()
                        function Getallitem() {

                            $http.get('/Coupons/GetStore').success(function (data) {
                                $scope.Store = data;
                            });
                        }

                    $scope.SelectedValue = function (item) {
                        document.getElementById("txtStorename").value = item;
                    }
                });   
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: please explain the problem you are facing!

Comment: Sir the list pops up on form load.there is a drop down list below the textbox which comes on load .what i want is that the list should show up on keyup event of textbox . and i cant find a solution to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {};
        $scope.obj.showList = false;
        
        $scope.Getallitem = function(){
            $scope.Store = []; 
            $scope.Store[0] = {}
            $scope.Store[1] = {};
            $scope.Store[0].StoreName = "Test1";
            $scope.Store[1].StoreName = "Test2";           
        }
         $scope.Getallitem();
         console.log($scope.Store);

        $scope.SelectedValue = function (item) {
            $scope.obj.showList = false;
            $scope.obj.sname = item;
        }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" ng-keyup="obj.showList = true;" class="myInput form-control" name="txtStorename" id="txtStorename" placeholder="Search for Store.." title="Type in a Store" data-error-message="Please enter StoreName" ng-model="obj.sname">
    <ul ng-if="obj.sname && obj.showList" id="myUL" ng-repeat="StoreList in Store| filter:{StoreName:sname}">
      <li ng-click="SelectedValue(StoreList.StoreName)">{{StoreList.StoreName}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-show="(Store|filter:obj.sname).length==0" style="color:red;font-weight:bold">No Result Found</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sir i tried scope.sname = item but it never worked out .

Comment: and sir this code is working fine but the problem is on emptying the text box the list should close and on selecting the list item the list should minimize to that selected value

Comment: Sir this is perfect but my list is from database and uve hardcoded the list so how do i call that in scope.getallitem function()

Comment: @AsadKapadia like you were calling in your code, i edited the code in snippet to show that its working.

Comment: Sir is it possible to use keyboard ( Up and Down key) for navigation of list .like to scroll on list

Comment: Yeah its possible, but instead of building your own autocomplete feature use a library for it.

Comment: Sir how is that possible in my case . If u dont mind ?

Comment: try this link: https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv,  you have to customize it according to your requirement.

Comment: Sir i tried but it aint getting implement is there any thing else to be used